# How to determine the (printed) length of a std::string with tab characters expanded?

Tags: c++, string

Given a C++ `std::string` variable which includes tab characters, is it possible to determine the length of that string as it would appear on the "screen"? i.e.:

```
std::string var = "\t\t\t";
std::cout << var.length();          // result: 3
std::cout << printed_length(var);   // result: 3*(# of spaces per tab)
```

Comment: I'm assuming there is no cross platform solution to this. Not sure though. Specify your target OS anyway.

Comment: The width of a tab cannot be known, unless you know exactly where your text is being rendered (then the renderer would know the width of a tab compared to a space)

Comment: @the_drow: I'm currently using MinGW GCC 3.4.5 with MSYS on Windows XP.

Comment: @Bob Fincheimer: I figured that might be the case. Is there no way to determine that measurement, perhaps from the output stream itself?

Comment: Consider that strings and streams can hold UTF8.  If so, the question is to use a unicode library.  Some single characters are multiple codepoints, some codepoints are not characters at all, some codepoints are multiple `chars`...  And that's _aside_ from not knowing about the rendering surface.  And no, streams don't know that either.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: for that matter, strings and streams can also hold SHIFT_JIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not easily. It's impossible without specific knowledge of the "screen" involved (really, the software driving the output), because tab expansion varies so widely. There are four fairly obvious possibilities, based on fixed expansion vs. expansion to a multiple of something, and based on character cells vs. some other fixed measurement (e.g., for proportional fonts). There are also "smart tabs" with even more complex criteria, where one tab's expansion may depend upon another tab.

On a typical "console" that'll be expansion mod 8 character cells. To deal with that, you'll not only have to count the tabs, but also look at the position of each tab in the string. You'll also have to make some assumptions (or provide a parameter) about the position of the beginning of the string relative to a tab stop.

Bottom line: if you want to do something like this, you'll have to do it yourself, based on knowledge of how tabs will be expanded on your target.

Answer (score 3):

We'll make the simplifying assumption that the text in the string is the only text on a line, or that it starts on a tab boundary.

Each tab character will expand to a different number of spaces based on the number of characters prior to it.

```
expansion_count = n_spaces - (current_count % n_spaces);
```